# AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'encode', using Apache Cassandra and Python

Tags: python, cassandra-2.0

i'm using python to insert a dataframe in apache cassandra, but the error AttributeError is returning: 'bool' object has no attribute 'encode'

```
cluster = Cluster(['127.0.0.1'])
session = cluster.connect()

def acessa_banco(palavra):
       session.execute("""CREATE KEYSPACE IF NOT EXISTS %s WITH replication = {'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' :'1' }""" % palavra)
       session.set_keyspace(palavra)
       session.execute("""
              create table if not exists stg_pesquisa_twitter(
                      usuario           text
                     ,localizacao       text
                     ,total_amigos      int 
                     ,total_seguidores  int 
                     ,total_listas      int         
                     ,total_likes       int          
                     ,status_verificado textﬁ‹
                     ,total_status      int  
                     ,total_retweet     int  
                     ,tweet             text
                     ,PRIMARY KEY(usuario)       
              ) WITH comment='Informacao dos twitter mais pesquisados';
       """
       )

       # insert da tabela 
       query = "insert into stg_pesquisa_twitter (usuario, localizacao, total_amigos, total_seguidores, total_listas, total_likes, status_verificado, total_status, total_retweet, tweet) \
                values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"

   prepared = session.prepare(query)
   for index, row in txt.iterrows():
          session.execute(prepared
                         ,(row['usuario']
                         , row['localizacao']
                         , row['total_amigos']
                         , row['total_seguidores']
                         , row['total_listas']
                         , row['total_likes']
                         , row['status_verificado']
                         , row['total_status']
                         , row['total_retweet']
                         , row['tweet'])
                         )
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

question is old but still unanswered and I encountered a similar error today, so:

Based on your table definition, the fields are either 'text' or 'int'.

You are preparing a query, so Cassandra Driver will try to convert your provided values properly to insert them into the query.

This error says that the Driver tried to encode a boolean value just like it was a string:

```py
False.encode() # this would not work in Python
"false".encode() # this works
```

So, to at least one of the columns defined as 'text' you are providing a boolean value. To fix the problem, find which of the values was a boolean and convert it to string.